# .col-lg-offset not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I recently switched from Foundation to Bootstrap and it seems great, but I am unable to figure out why the offset isn't working for me here. Would anyone be able to help?
Note that I'm using Bootstrap 4.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo description">
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <p>Some text goes here...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you all in advance for your help.

Comment: Please go read [ask], and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hy @ZimSystem, I am using Bootstrap 4

Comment: Please [refer to the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns) before asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try

```html
<div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
            <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
```

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thank you so so much Preeti, that worked. It's strange because I on w3schools they wrote .col-sm-offset-* so I just assumed it was that. Has it changed recently?
But thank you ever so much once again, I really appreciate!